# Conditional wrap in Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, conditional-statements, thymeleaf

I'm looking for the method how I can avoid logic duplication in my `Thymeleaf` template in order to produce conditional wrapper. Say, I want wrap some group of tags inside another one on some condition. I've tried this one:

```
<div th:if="${hide}" th:remove="tag">
   ... some block ...
</div>
```

But it totally removes all blocks in case when `hide` parameter is set to `false`, and draws `... some block ...` without `<div>` wrapper when `hide` is `true`.

I don't want to duplicate this structure in style like:

```
<div th:if="${!hide}">
   ... some block ...
</div>
<th:block th:if="${hide}">
   ... some block ...
</th>
```

Is it possible at all?

**EDIT** And I don't want to wrap my `... some block ...` into another fragment. It is obvious decision, but it isn't what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it said in [this issue](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/224) it can be easily achieved in such style:

```
<div th:remove="${hide} ? tag : none">
   ... some block ...
</div>
```